# Salto de Pagina PhpExcel o PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Porfis como realizo un salto de pagina en PHPEXCEL o PHPSPREADSHEET

[image: Me refiero a un salto de pagina de esta forma]

Comment: PHPExcel es obsoleto, lo comento aquí para que conste. En cuanto a la pregunta, ¿qué has intentado? ¿Has revisado la documentación de `PHPSpreadSheet`?

Answer (score 0):

```
PHPEXCEL
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setBreak( 'A15', PHPExcel_Worksheet::BREAK_ROW );
```

> PHPSPREADSHEET
>
> ```
> $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setBreak('A10', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet::BREAK_ROW);
> ```
>
> https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/

ya lo encontre en su manual, asi habia sido, para los que aun no lo sepan.

Comment: ¿Dónde lo encontraste? Pon al menos el enlace para que sirva de referencia a usuarios con problemas parecidos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714184/php-excel-jump-to-next-page

Comment: lo encontre en la misma pagina pero en ingles, solamente lo traduci y listo, por que no lo encontraba hace tiempo, nunca pude encontrarlo como salto de pagina.

Comment: Entendido, pero como te decía, PHPExcel está obsoleto. Quizá conviene que pruebes con PHPSpreadSheet, pues es muy parecido, como se explica [aquí en el apartado **Setting printing breaks on a row or column**](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/)

Comment: tienes razon, tambien uso el phpspreadsheet, y segun lo veo es casi lo mismo y mejor en algunas cosas.